What process modifies my PATH variable?
Something somewhere prepends my PATH variable and this causes the wrong python version to be loaded when in Tmux (but not in the base terminal). I have inspected all the files that get sourced at initialisation: .bashrc, /etc/profile, /etc/bashrc but there is no trace of any command that would add the problematic line to PATH. Is there some way of seeing which processes modify the variable at initialisation?

Generally, the ways that the environment is modified is given by a few specific files.  There are the standard ones run on system startup:

~/.profile
~/.bashrc (only for bash sessions) (rarely also ~/.bash_profile)
/etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
Files in /etc/profile.d

There are also some additional files only set environment variables, using a secific syntax (see man environment.d)

files in ~/.config/environment.d/ and /etc/environment.d/
Apparently also files in /usr/local/lib/environment.d/ and /usr/lib/environment.d/, though I've never seen them used.
/etc/environment

Lastly, there is /etc/security/pam_env.conf, which also handles some other things, but provides some fancypants features.
You'll need to go through all those files; you can use grep PATH /etc/environment.d/* to do it quickly.
